# VS2012 Server Explorer - Cannot Access Windows Azure Storage

Tags: visual-studio-2012, azure-storage

I have VS2012 Ultimate SP3 and a Windows Azure account.  I have published an MVC 3 application, using an Azure SQL Server DB without problems.  I have installed the Azure SDK (v2.1) and can access the database and web site through the Server Explorer.

I have now created an Azure Storage Container however, I am unable to access it through VS2012 Server Explorer. I get an error dialog titled "Storage Account Key Required" stating "The current storage account key is invalid. Please provide a new storage account key." I try re-entering the key and get the same error.

I have checked the key and it is valid. I have tried accessing the Azure Storage, using that same key, through a third party product and it works fine.

I've tried the usual uninstall / re-install, delete Azure Storage and re-create, create new and different container, all to no avail.

Does anyone know why I get this error or, even better, how to fix it?

TIA

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution, after many hours of research, investigation and trial and error, is to ensure that the date and time on your PC is set correctly.  Mine was one hour out. After setting it to the correct time, everything works perfectly.

Comment: do you have any more info on this. I'm receiving this error and my clock seems to be correct.

Comment: The clocks went back one hour on Sunday just gone. I wonder if your problem may be related to that?

Comment: My date and time is set to sync with time.windows.com. I have ensured that the time is correct but the problem remains.