# Can't publish to Azure from VS 2013 RC (403 Forbidden)

Tags: azure, azure-storage, visual-studio-2013

I'm running VS 2013 Preview with Azure 2.1 SDK installed.

I have an MVC project, right clicked on it, and created a cloud project for it.  The publish wizard asks me to "sign in and download credentials"... cool, no problem.  I do that and then import the file that's downloaded.  The wizard then shows my list of subscriptions.  I pick the one I want and enter a name for my new service. But then when it then goes to publish, the output/activity windows says "Warning: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden."  and that line is repeated every 15 seconds).

I've tried nuking everything (certificates on the Azure portal, the cloud project in visual studio) and redownloading/importing the publish settings, but get the same result.

Probably related is that when I try looking at the storage service in the Server Explorer window, it pops up a window prompting me to enter the account key... that form comes pre-populated with the same key I see on the portal and copy/pasting it into the form doesn't resolve the problem nor does regenerating the key and copy/pasting that.

I also tried using a different subscription to see if that is somehow the problem but got the same result.

No idea what to try next but this inability to publish is a major blocker for me.  Any ideas?

Comment: Please check if you have fiddler (or anything which could act as a proxy between VS and Service Management API) running. 403 error is usually the result of Service Management API not finding the management certificate in the request.

Comment: @GauravMantri - Yup, this is without Fiddler.  When I have Fiddler running, it fails in a different but presumably related way... the publish wizard pops a message box saying `Authentication failed. Verify that your credentials are valid or download them again.`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OMG I finally figured it out.  My dev PC was unplugged for a while as I upgraded the hard drive and I guess the clock lost time.  Apparently if you system time is not in sync with real-world-time, Azure returns authorization errors.  Discovered after many many many hours of googling and eventually finding [VS2012 Server Explorer - Cannot Access Windows Azure Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18031008/vs2012-server-explorer-cannot-access-windows-azure-storage) which solved the problem with 3 clicks

Comment: Just had the same problem. It would have been less frustrating if the 403 would have been a bit informative about the actual problem.

Comment: If you are ever in SoCal, Riverside - I owe you a beer. That was exactly my issue - except I'm using a VM that lost time. I don't know that I ever would have found that.