# Access Azure Storage from VS server explorer

Tags: windows, azure-storage

i'm trying to view my blob data from VS2013 but every time i'm trying to expand the arrow of the Blobs, i got:"The current storage account key is invalid. Please provide a new storage account key."
it doesn't matter that i try again and again to recreate/regenerate the key and insert it into the "Account key" text box but nothing help

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3hwOvf_Jqt0YXlCV0ZYdXpzNWM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: does selecting 'Use https' work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this problem was posted over on this thread: [VS2012 Server Explorer - Cannot Access Windows Azure Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18031008/vs2012-server-explorer-cannot-access-windows-azure-storage)

tl;dr Make sure your local PC's date and time are set correctly.